# Kafka rebalancing - assignement of Kafka consumers to partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

When a new Kafka consumer joins/leaves a consumer group, Kafka runtime triggers a rebalancing process so that a new assignment/mapping of partitions to the new set of consumers is performed. I kindly have three questions on the rebalancing process:

(1) Is it possible to plug in somehow a custom rebalancing algorithm, other than the ones already implemented?

(2) Is it possible to pass an external variable to the custom algorithm?

(3) Is it possible to dynamically and selectively launch a rebalancing process, other than the known cases (such as  when consumer leaves, join etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use `partition.assignment.strategy` to set a custom assignment algorithm. The custom class needs to implement [`ConsumerPartitionAssignor`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerPartitionAssignor.html).
2. The assignor can do any necessary logic to retrieve values from the environment or other places.
3. Since Kafka 2.6, you can use [`enforceRebalance()`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#enforceRebalance--) to trigger one.